# Would it be necessary to wait/sleep the bash script before rebooting the system after executing commands?

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian

I wrote a bash script that enables me to have all my cloud servers with a base configuration. Upon completing the script, I'd like to know if I should put a timer for 30 seconds (or so) before rebooting the system. I'm not sure if linux, specifically Debian, needs time to post-process any installation/upgrades before reboot and what command before issuing the reboot would ensure that the system is no longer 'busy' such as wait or sleep.

```
# Install and Update packages
apt-get update
apt-get -y install <list-of-packages>
apt-get -y dist-upgrade

# Reboot System
reboot
```

Comment: This is an ancient and unnecessary superstitious habit from decades ago, but I still like to run `sync` before `reboot` or `shutdown -r now`, or even `sync; sync; sync; reboot` ("I tell you three times" makes it real :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Waiting is not necessary. Once apt has exited you may safely reboot.

Comment: I noticed after running apt, the CPU usage remains fairly high for 20-30 seconds afterwards (40-60%) and then drops to 1%. I just want to be sure I'm not forcing anything to stop before reboot.

Comment: Was it for apt itself or something else? I've never noticed that.

Comment: The system was idle before running apt. I can't remember specifically what packages - it was likely either apache2 or mysql/mariadb but I did run other packages alongside it as well.